# I cannot solve django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'XXX' is not a registered namespace with Django3

Tags: django, django-templates

I cannot solve "django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'XXX' is not a registered namespace" problem with Django3.1.1.

I have seen similar issues on many websites, I cannot solve mine.

The error message on browser is `NoReverseMatch at / 'shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho' is not a registered namespace`

The error message on terminal is `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho' is not a registered namespace`

I just want to show index.html on "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" page.

./conf/settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for conf project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.1.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'xxx'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'index.apps.IndexConfig',
    'shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho.apps.ShiharaisaisokumoushitateshoConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'conf.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'conf.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ja'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

./conf/urls.py

```
"""conf URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('index.urls')),
]
```

./index/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'index'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho/', include('shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho.urls', namespace='shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho')),
]
```

./index/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    return render(request, './index/index.html')
```

./templates/index/base.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Something</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
{% block content %}
    This is index
{% endblock %}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

./templates/index/index.html

```
{%  extends './base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="col text-center">
        <a href="{%  url 'shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho:shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho1' %}">shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho:shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho1</a><br>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: There's alot going on here, but does `shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho.urls` exist? Its looking for an app called `shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho` and its associated urls file

Comment: @leelum1 Thanks your comment. Do you mean there is urls.py in shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho folder or shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho.urls file?

Comment: There should be a urls.py file in the shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho folder. That's what your link is looking for

Comment: @leelum1 There is  urls.py file in the shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho folder already.
I found another solution. I answer this problem with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I modified below urls.py files, then the problem is solved.

./conf/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('index.urls')),
    path('shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho/', include('shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho.urls')),
]
```

./shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views

app_name = 'shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho'


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho1, name='shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho1'),
]
```

What should I do is I have to specify URL in ./conf/urls.py and empty URL in shiharaisaisokumoushitatesho in urls.py.